# Voting results query not getting the candidate if vote is 0

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I will present my problem here:

I have 2 tables named "Thesis" and "Votes". The table "Thesis" has two columns namely:

- id
- thesis_title

and the table "table Votes" has the following columns

- id
- thesis_title
- student_num

This is my dummy data

```
Thesis table
ID    thesis_title 
1     Online portal for FGC 
2     Reservation System 
3     Restaurant System 

table Votes 
ID    thesis_title           student_num
1     Online portal for Fgc  201311357
2     Reservation System     201311358
3     Online portal for FGC  201311359
```

My output is like this:

```
thesis_title           votes
Online portal for fgc   2 
Reservation system      1
<no restaurant system>
```

desired result must be

```
thesis_title           votes
Online portal for fgc   2 
Reservation system      1
Restaurant system       0
```

Here my latest query

```
$this->db->select('thesis.thesis_title,count(votes.thesis_title) as votes')
->from('thesis')->join('votes','thesis.thesis_title= votes.thesis_title','left')->group_by('votes.thesis_title');
```

Comment: you need a `LEFT JOIN` and to impute `0` for `NULL`

Comment: What does your actual sql look like if you use `$this->db->last_query()`?

Answer (score 0):

If I convert your php query to an SQL script, I am able to produce the correct output.

```
SELECT a.thesis_title, COUNT(b.thesis_title) AS votes FROM thesis a INNER JOIN votes b ON a.thesis_title = b.thesis_title GROUP BY b.thesis_title ORDER BY votes DESC;
```

The restaurant system votes will not appear if you use INNER JOIN, as it checks records matching in both columns.

Have you tried querying it directly in your database?

Comment: But he *is* using a left join... The last arg in `->join('votes','thesis.thesis_title= votes.thesis_title','left')`.

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a bad entity-relationship model, because you need a foreign key in your votes table and make a join with this foreing key (votes) with id (thesis).
Best table structure

```
Thesis                  Votes 
id                      id
thesis_title            thesis_fk
                        student_num
```

query in CI

```
$query = $this->db->select('t.id, t.thesis_title, v.id as id2, v.student_num')
->from('Thesis t')
->join('Votes v', 't.id = c.thesis_fk', 'right');

return $query->result();
```